# Socket.io unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I've got node.js installed and running on pc. When I make a pakage.json as shown below, then in that folder run cmd

```
npm install socket.io
```

or

```
npm install
```

it gives the error

```
unable to verify the first certificate
```

How can I fix this?

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "app",
  "dependencies": {
  "socket.io": "latest"
},
  "author": "shadryck"
}
```

NOTE: I am completely new to node.js and socket.io. I'm just trying to get started with it somehow.

NOTE: if for some reason you're going to downvote this at least explain why. I do have done my research and was unable to find an answer anywhere.

UPDATE: fixed it by reinstalling node.js and restarting pc after not having restarted it for a very long time.

UPDATE: installed python, but now its whining for even more errors. [screenie](http://3.1m.yt/EJ6DHqC7y.png)

Comment: Do you know if you're sitting behind a proxy? Also what does `npm config get [ca]` return?

Comment: @john-omahoney I have never touched a proxy so I guess its safe to assume I'm not using proxy. `npm config get [ca]` returns undefined

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you're not behind a proxy, I think this may be an issue with the SSL Root Certificate Authorities trusted.

Firstly you can try force NPM to use known registrars

```
npm config set ca ""
```

If this doesn't work, it's perhaps due to missing certs from the install.

You can try reinstall/upgrade NPM with the appropriate certs by doing the following in order

```
npm config set ca ""
npm install npm -g
npm config delete ca
```

If that still fails you might have to forcibly download the missing CA's. Luckily there's a library for fixing this. Unfortunately there's a security pitfall in the process. (I'm open to hearing improvements!).

Firstly, turn off ssl in npm (this is the security pitfall) by using

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

then you can install

```
npm install ssl-root-cas
```

then simply type node and in the REPL type

```
var sslRootCAs = require('ssl-root-cas/latest')
sslRootCAs.inject()
```

then turn back on SSL and test

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Comment: `npm config set ca ""`
`npm install npm -g`
`npm config delete ca`
returned exactly the same error.
`unable to verify the first certificate` 
Turned off scrict-ssl and got next error. `write EIO` This is driving me nuts (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻ stuff just doesn't make sense. Should I try reinstalling node.js next or something?

Comment: @shadryck Certainly wouldn't hurt!

Comment: @john-omahoney Alright, reinstalled node.js, restarted pc and ran `npm install socket.io` again and got something different this time. It's now whining about python missing `Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable`

Comment: @john-omahoney I'm really starting to dislike node.js now. I'm genuinely starting to think that even my very first pong game has been organized better than this mess called node.js. Sigh. Next errors, `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT` , `write EIO`. Had some trouble with python path but it appears to be fixed now. Any further ideas on how to get out of this mess? [screenie](http://3.1m.yt/EJ6DHqC7y.png)

Comment: Two things from looking at the screenshot. First try not to use spaces in the names of folders. I can lead to unpredictable behaviour so perhaps rename that. Number two is that it might be an issue with node_gyp which has a dependency on some windows stuff. Make sure .net 2.5(I think is installed) if all else fails, download the latest free MS Visual studio and it should work

Comment: @john-omahoney screw it. Im totally done with this node.js crap. Can't do jack without bloating my pc with random frameworks that might or might not carry a fix for a weird bug that doesn't even make sense to begin with. Since you did bring me to get an answer for original question I'll accept your answer.

Comment: `npm config set strict-ssl false` is what i want.

Answer (score 0):

You might also be able to just switch to use the regular HTTP registry instead of the default HTTPS one by running:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

As mentioned in [npm issue 8872](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8872)